# Why doesn't this recursive regex capture the entire code block?

Tags: regex, perl, regex-recursion

I'm trying to write a recursive regular expression to capture code blocks, but for some reason it seems to not be capturing them properly. I would expect the code below to capture the full body of the function, but instead it only captures the contents of the first `if` statement.

It's almost like the `.+?` is somehow gobbling up the first `{`, but it's supposed to be non-greedy so I don't understand why it would.

What is causing it to act this way?

**Script:**

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $text = << "END";
int max(int x, int y)
{
    if (x > y)
    {
        return x;
    }
    else
    {
        return y;
    }
}
END

# Regular expression to capture balanced "{}" groups
my $regex = qr/
    \{              # Match opening brace
        (?:         # Start non-capturing group
            [^{}]++ #     Match non-brace characters without backtracking
            |       #     or
            (?R)    #     Recursively match the entire expression
        )*          # Match 0 or more times
    \}              # Match closing brace
/x;

# is ".+?" gobbling up the first "{"?
# What would cause it to do this?
if ($text =~ m/int\s.+?($regex)/s){
    print $1;
}
```

**Output:**

```
{
        return x;
    }
```

**Expected Output:**

```
{
    if (x > y)
    {
        return x;
    }
    else
    {
        return y;
    }
}
```

I know that there is a [`Text::Balanced`](http://search.cpan.org/~shay/Text-Balanced-2.03/lib/Text/Balanced.pm) module for this purpose, but I am attempting to do this by hand in order to learn more about regular expressions.

Comment: Maybe a version problem, `(?R)` requires Perl 5.10+

Comment: @ Aaron, I have version 5.20

Comment: @anubhava, the recursive expression seems to work on it's own, but not inside the `if` statement with more added to it.

Comment: You might enjoy [this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ob6YHpcXmTg) by Damian Conway, which explains how he wrote a single massive regex to parse Perl. Also look at his module PPR, which is on CPAN.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`(?R)` recurses into the whole pattern – but what is the whole pattern? When you embed the quoted `$regex` into `/int\s.+?($regex)/`, the pattern is recompiled and `(?R)` refers to the new pattern. That's not what you intended.

I'd recommend you use named captures instead so that you can recurse by name. Change the `$regex` like

```
/(?<nestedbrace> ... (?&nestedbrace) ...)/
```

If you want to avoid extra captures, you can use the `(?(DEFINE) ...)` syntax to declare named regex patterns that can be called later:

```
my $define_nestedbrace_re = qr/(?(DEFINE)
  (?<nestedbrace ... (?&nestedbrace) ...)
)/x;
```

Then: `/int\s.+?((?&nestedbrace))$define_nestedbrace_re/`

That won't create additional captures. However, it is not generally possible to write encapsulated regex fragments. Techniques like preferring named captures instead of numbered captures can help here.

Comment: that works, but adds another problem. if I change my `if` statement to print `$1` and `$2` it will now print something for `$2`, but the way I'm going to use this pattern having it capture a group internally can make the code that uses it confusing.

Comment: I basically want to capture the codeblock and leave `$2` undefined so it only captures the groups that I explicitly ask for.

Comment: @tjwrona1992 see my update – by using `(?(DEFINE) ...)` blocks you can structure your regex to avoid extra captures.

Comment: Can you explain the `((?&nestedbrace))`? Why is that needed before using `$define_nested_brace_re?

Comment: @tjwrona1992 The `$define_nested_brace_re` pattern only defines a named subpattern. It does not match it by itself and does not capture the results. The `(?(DEFINE) …)` is very much like a `sub` declaration. You could rewrite the pattern to define the pattern and also run it, but I find that defining and invoking subpatterns separately is more maintainable for large regexes.

Comment: For this scenario I think defining and running it in one would be simpler as far as readability, but trying that I end up having another problem. I added an extra line to the text saying `more stuff` or something else random, then changed my expression to `if ($text =~ m/int\s(.+?)$regex(.+)/s){ print $1; print $2; }` but after executing it I get an error saying `$2` is undefined.

Comment: There is nothing obviously wrong with that regex. This might be an unrelated problem, and these comments are not a suitable place to debug it.

Comment: Okay I think I may need to post a new question for this new problem, because it is really too much to describe here.

Answer (score 1):

You can change your recursive pattern to this one:

```
/int\s+.*?  (
    \{              # Match opening brace
        (?:         # Start non-capturing group
            [^{}]++ # Match non-brace chars without backtracking
            |       # OR
            (?-1)   # Recursively match the previous group
        )*          # Match 0 or more times
    \}
)/sx
```

- Note use of `(?-1)` instead of `(?R)` that recurses whole matched pattern.
- `(?-1)` is back-reference of previous capturing group.

[Updated RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lJ4bXk/4)

Comment: This also works, but just like the other solution it causes the recursive pattern to capture an extra group that is visible from the outer pattern. so `if ($text =~ m/int\s.+?($regex)/s)` will now capture something for `$1` as expected but also captures a value for `$2`.

Comment: The way this will be used I may want to capture a group before it, and after it like so `if ($text =~ m/int\s(.+?)$regex(.+?)/s) { print "$1, $2"; }` but now the second capture group will really be in `$3` which is really confusing.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get. There is only one capturing group here: https://regex101.com/r/lJ4bXk/3/

Comment: I think what I'm trying to ask in these comments should probably be a whole new question. These answers do what I asked in this question.